# Separate `index.d.ts` per Cypress entry, instead of one huge `index.d.ts`

Tags: typescript, cypress

We have the following standard Cypress & Typescript setup:

```
cypress/
  integration/
    foo/
      my-foo.spec.ts
    bar/
      my-bar.spec.ts
    baz/
      my-baz.spec.ts
    ...
  ...
  support/
    index.d.ts
    ...
```

We have many integration folders, and we are declaring each `Cypress.Command` in the `index.d.ts` in the support folder. The problem with this is that file is getting very large, and serves all integration entries at once.

Example of `index.d.ts`:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
      foo_doTheThing(): Chainable<any>;
      foo_doTheOtherThing(): Chainable<any>;
      bar_myFunc(): Chainable<any>;
      bar_helloWorld(): Chainable<any>;
      bar_clickTheThing(): Chainable<any>;
      baz_func(): Chainable<any>;
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is have each integration entry use just one `index.d.ts`, so that each one relates to its own entry.

How is this possible with Typescript?

Comment: If the contents of these Cypress commands being declared are only ever going to be used in one spec file, why not keep their definitions in those spec files and avoid polluting the Cypress namespace? My understanding of extending the Cypress namespace like this is to share common commands that are useful across multiple spec files.

Comment: @miqh that's a good point. I realise now I am heavily violating this best practice: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Best-Practices